# Confidence Interval for Inverse Gauss distribution with scipy.stats

Tags: python, scipy, probability

I am attempting to fit an inverse gauss distribution to data using the scipy.stats toolbox.  The data fits well using the following code:

```
import scipy.stats

dist = stats.invgauss
# fit a distribution to the data
dist_fit = dist.fit(data);
dist_model = dist(*dist_fit);
# find the distribution mean
dist_mu = dist_model.mean();
# find the distribution standard deviation
dist_std = dist_model.std();
```

Which produces a fit to the distribution that looks like this: [inverse_gaussian_fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vin6V.png).

I am trying to determine the confidence interval for the mean of this distribution.  From my understanding, the confidence interval of the mean is equal to the standard error of the mean (which is equal to the standard deviation divided by the square root of the number of tests) multiplied by the percent point function (which is equal to the inverse of the cumulative distribution function) at the confidence level desired.  I can do this using the following code:

```
# find the inverse gaussian standard error/confidence interval
dist_se = dist_std / np.sqrt(n);
dist_ci_l = dist_se * dist_model.ppf(0.05);
dist_ci_h = dist_se * dist_model.ppf(0.95);
```

Unfortunately, this produces unrealistic results like this: 
[inverse_gaussian_running_averages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIT2V.png).

How can I generate the asymmetric confidence interval for an inverse gauss function?  I have seen many applications where one assumes the confidence interval from a normal distribution, but that creates symmetric confidence intervals.

Comment: What are the estimated parameters for your inverse gaussian?

Comment: Mean:  41.79,  Standard Deviation:  47.48, Fitting parameter tuple:  (1.04,-4.66,44.48)

Comment: The traditional confidence interval makes the assumption of normality, so I don't know if what you're doing makes sense.  Also, your data doesn't seem like a very good fit to the distribution.  Also, see the comments here

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20169/how-to-compute-the-ci-of-an-inverse-gaussian-distribution

Comment: Thanks for the help, dfb.  What I ended up doing is using the ppf function to determine the value corresponding to a probability.  I then subtracted the mean from that.  Then I divided that by the square root of the number of tests.  This gives the an asymmetric range that the mean of another dataset with N tests will fall within 95% of the time.

Comment: A comment on your use of `dist.fit`: The support of the inverse Gaussian distribution is usually 0 <= x < inf (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution).  Like all of the continuous distributions in scipy, `invgauss` includes a `loc` (i.e. location) parameter, which corresponds to a shift of the support.  By default, the `fit` method treats `loc` as a free parameter that takes part in the fitting.  According to your previous comment,  your fit resulted in `loc=-4.66`, which is probably not what you want.  To constrain `loc` to be 0, use `dist_fit = dist.fit(data, floc=0)`.